# how to access the member num of struct bio_st in openSSL-1.1.1

Tags: openssl

in OpenSSL-1.1.1, struct bio_st is made opaque. To access the member of struct, APIs are provided. But I do not find an API to access the member int num of this struct.

in my application code with openSSL-1.0.2

```
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO( &fds );
FD_SET( b->num, &fds );
```

for this now I get

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'BIO {aka struct bio_st}'
>        FD_SET( b->num, &fds );

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use the macro `BIO_get_fd` to get this.